# How to use use_wallclock_as_timestamps?

Tags: c++, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

I try to use_wallclock_as_timestamps in the video.

The -use_wallclock_as_timestamps option tells FFmpeg to ignore those
timestamps and instead use the wallclock time:

```
if (s->use_wallclock_as_timestamps)
    pkt->dts = pkt->pts = av_rescale_q(av_gettime(), AV_TIME_BASE_Q, st->time_base);
```

But it do not work.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is this encode or decode? What is your scenario, why do you need wallclock time?

Answer (score 0):

You should rescale value from codec to stream timebase:

```
pkt->dts = pkt->pts = av_rescale_q(av_gettime(), codecContext->time_base, stream->time_base);
```